# Creation of Oracle wallet for hiding database credential in Java application

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g, java-6

I am using Java application (*.properties file for DB credential details) to connect with database, but my client is asking me to remove the databse credential details from the plain text files(i.e. .properties, .xml file) and use Oracle Wallet instead and encrypt the password.

Can anyone please let me know, how can i hide the database credential and use some other technique to achieve the database connectivity without disclosing the password details in the plain text files.

Answer (score 0):

- Store Encrypted password in properties file

  You can store encrypted the password (probably with MD5 hash). Decrypt the password before connecting to database. check this for more details on implementing MD5: [Encrypt and decrypt a password in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592010/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-password-in-java)
- Oracle Wallet

  look here - [What is correct JDBC URL syntax if Oracle wallets are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634196/what-is-correct-jdbc-url-syntax-if-oracle-wallets-are-used)