# JDBC connection from Jython

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jython, wallet

I encounter a problem with JDBC connector called from Jython script.

I would like to connect to an Oracle server using Wallet. This is the connection part :

```
walletLocation=str(os.environ['HOME']+"./oracle")
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin",  str(os.environ['TNS_ADMIN']))
System.setProperty("oracle.net.wallet_location", str("(SOURCE=(METHOD=file)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY="+walletLocation+")))"))
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:/@myService";
ods = OracleDataSource()
ods.setURL(url)
ocon = ods.getConnection()
```

The result:
    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

- TNS_ADMIN is set and tnsnames.ora contains the definition of myService
- sqlnet.ora contains the WALLET_LOCATION
- I can connect to my Oracle server with the command :sqlplus /@myService

Now if I add these properties to my connection:

```
walletProperties.put("user","oracle_user")
walletProperties.put("password","1234")
ods.setConnectionProperties(walletProperties)
```

The connection is OK.. so JDBC read correctly "myService" in the tnsnames.ora.

My feeling is that the property "oracle.net.wallet_location" is not used...

Someone has a clue to resolve this riddle ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does the information in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7634196/2144390) help at all?

Comment: Hi,
Which kind of additional information I can add ?

I've try to replace thin jdbc by oci... and it's works.
But I don't understand why thin connector doesn't works..

Comment: This should work with thin too. Have you added oraclepki.jar in your classpath? This jar is needed to be able to open the wallet in java and the driver needs it.